# About catch the bus, train etc

Tags: meaning

I found the two meanings of the verb 'to catch the train, bus etc' in British English:

1) we are getting the stop/station, waiting and boarding

2) we are getting the stop/station, waiting and boarding and do all these things IN TIME.

There is the example from the related topic (BrE):

How shall we get to London next week?" "I've looked at the timetable, and I think we should catch the 10:49"

and I can't undestarnd how this example reffers with my two meanings of the verb 'to catch the train, bus etc'? I think it is more natural to use 'to take' or 'to get' instead of 'to catch'.

Comment: 'catch' is a perfectly fine alternative to get or take. And it makes it seem more sporting.

Comment: This is essentially a re-asking of your other question.  See the answers to that question.

Comment: Sorry. But I really can't see the difference between 'to catch' and 'to get/take' here. And we are only exploring using 'take/get' in that topic but not 'to catch'

Comment: @Selio Read my answer to your other question.  get/catch are essentially interchangeable.

Comment: Yes. You wrote: "Now, as to get in AmE: Get carries the implication of boarding the vehicle in question (and in most uses is interchangeable with catch -- e.g. catch a cab, etc.)" But I pointed 2 times in this topic that I'm interesting in British English. I understand your explanation really well, thank you, but I'm not confident that it is the same in BrE. In BrE 'to  get' is different from 'to get' in BrE. In AmE it is like 'to catch' but in BrE it is like 'to take' I think. Or may be I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples of *getting the station/stop* sound wrong to my ears. At least in American English they would be wrong. In any event, both *catch* and *take* can be used for transportation. However, there's a difference between the two. *Catch* means,

> **4** reach in time and board (a train, bus, or aircraft): they caught the 12.15 from Oxford.

And *take* means,

> to use as a route or means.

So you can use both for the same purpose, but they mean different things.